# saving foreign key relations using DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to save foreign key relations using serializer , I don't know where I am wrong here i have spent hours thinking about his now , don't seem to understand where the error lies, create method is not working and it's not saving any data either

```
 class Catalogs(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Catalog.objects.all()
    serializer_class  = CatalogSerializer


    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.data:
            serialized_data = self.get_serializer(
               data = request.data
            )
```

**serializer**

```
class CatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    catalog_products = CatalogProductsSerializer(source = 'catalogproducts_set',many=True)
    
    def create(self,validated_data):
        client_id = validated_data.pop('id')
        catalog_obj = Catalog.objects.create(
                client = User.objects.get(id=client_id),
            )
        
        CatalogProducts.objects.create(
            catalog = catalog_obj,
            **validated_data
        )
        return catalog_obj

    
    class Meta:
        model = Catalog
        fields = ['created_by','client','catalog_products','created_datetime','is_active']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what is wrong without seeing the error message.

But here are the thing that you need to change:

`serialized_data` is not the actual serialized data but the serializer instance. You need to call `save()` method of the serializer to save the instance and `data()` method to get the serialized data.

```
serializer_cls = self.get_serializer()
serializer = serializer_cls(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

catalog_instance = serializer.save()
catalog_serialized_data = serializer.data()
```